# Laravel 5.2, Delete associated files upon cascade delete

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

My question is in regard to using Eloquent when deleting a file in a model, that is related to another model, which is related to another model, all via foreign constraints:

- Dealer hasMany Customers
- Customer hasMany Documents

The Documents model contains the 'document_name' column.

So in essence, I want to delete a file when I delete a Dealer;

Dealers->Customers->Documents->document_name.

I put a delete method on the Documents model, but how do I get it to defer all the way up when I delete a Dealer? I will also follow suit when I delete a Customer.

Am I doing this the right way, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create an event for when this model is being deleted

```
<?php

class Dealer extends Model
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Customer');
    }

    // this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($dealer) {
             // do all of the logic for deleting customers and files here
             $dealer->customers->get()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the process of deleting the customers and files may not be correct here, but the concept is generally the same.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into events. On a separate note, I saw an example of a developer overriding the delete method on the model and 'defer it up the chain' to another method using `parent::delete()`...this seemed like another solution and perhaps cleaner. Any thoughts on this method?